# Python Deque Array Ring Buffer

Tags: python, buffer, ctypes, deque

My goal for this is to:

- use `(capacity * ctypes.py_object)()` to allocate a block of memory,
- use geometric expansion with a factor of 2,
- use circular buffer approach to handling indexes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I am very stuck. Thanks!

```
class deque:

capacity = 10

def __init__(self, size):
    self._data = (capacity * ctypes.py_object)
    self._size = 0
    self._front = 0

def isEmpty(self):
    return self._size == 0

def __len__(self):
    return self._size

def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.list[index]

def addFront(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)

def addRear(self, item):
    self.items.insert(0, item)

def removeFront(self):
    return self.items.pop()

def removeRear(self):
    return self.items.pop(0)
```

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization.  Did you try collections.deque first, profile it, and use that to arrive at the conclusion that you need ctypes (which is often slow unless you spend a lot of time in the C)?

Comment: @dstromberg yea i am kind of new, i am having trouble wrapping my head around how i implement a deque with circular buffer and geometric expansion